# HTML window open in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This works fine in Chrome. But in IE it opens a window, and the current window from where the hyperlink is clicked goes blank. How do I fix this?

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://register.com?uuId=86C2EC58','mywindow')">
    86C2EC58
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 'target="_blank"' inside the `a` tag? If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes.But no difference

Comment: Maybe try adding `return false`? Or make it a button and use `onclick`? Or, better-yet, stop using JavaScript in URL's and attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `;void(0)` after your `window.open`
like this:

```
    <a href="javascript:window.open('http://register.com?uuId=86C2EC58','mywindow'); void(0)">86C2EC58</a>
```

Or just use the A element without the javascript and with target="_blank":

```
<a href="http://register.com?uuId=86C2EC58" target="_blank">86C2EC58</a>
```

Comment: Could you explain why putting ```;void(0)``` makes IE happy?

Comment: Adding void(0) helps lot but it opens a new smaller window.. I was expecting it to open a larger window (as larger as parent window) so that it can open as a new tab than a new window.

Comment: you can specify the width and height of the new window. for example read here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp  I dont really understand what you are trying to do but for opening a link in new tab I would use a regular link with target="_blank"